# How to identify internal llvm functions?

Tags: function, llvm

I need to make a method that returns only the name of the functions that are **internal**. In the example below, I hope to return: `_GLOBAL__I_a`

Example:

```
define i32 @ main (i32% argc, i8 **% argv) {...
define i32 @ _Z9Factoriali (i32% M) {nounwind ...
define internal void @ _GLOBAL__I_a () section. "text.startup" {...
```

What is the best way to identify internal functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check whether a function has internal linkage by invoking `Function::hasInternalLinkage()` on it. So your method should iterate over all the functions in the module and return the ones for which `hasInternalLinkage` returns true.